# Why is my input field not allowing me to edit the content?

Tags: html, reactjs

I cannot change the value of this input field in the browser.

```
<div>
  cart.products.map((item) => (
      <div className="" key={item.product._id}>
    <div
      className={`${styles.quantity} col-6 d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center col-md-2  
       d-md-block mb-2 mb-md-0`}>
      <input
        className="form-control-sm text-center mb-2"
        type="number"
        name="quantity"
        value={item.quantity}
        onChange={(event) => handleChange(event.target)}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  )
</div>;
```

The cart data looks like this and is being pulled from redux;

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5f15ee2c0b94bf240470d70d"
},
"user": {
    "$oid": "5f15ee2c0b94bf240470d70c"
},
"products": [
    {
        "quantity": 2,
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f47d8f2a0c7f4238cb82bf6"
        },
        "product": {
            "$oid": "5f1864917c213e0f5779ee48"
        }
    },
```

}

handleChange:

```
const handleChange = (event.target) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setQuantity(value);
  };
```

Make a deep copy of the cart from the reducer thereby giving the component its own copy of the cart;

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCart(cartIn);
  }, [cartIn]);


const [cart, setCart] = useState({});

const getCart = (cart) => {
   setCart(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart)));
 };
```

Reducer code:

```
export const CartReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case ReducerTypes.SET_CART:
      console.log("cart", payload);
      const subtotal = computeSubtotal(payload);
      addCartToLocalStorage(payload, subtotal);
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: payload,
        subtotal: subtotal,
        numberOfItems: payload.products.length,
      };
  }
};
```

Destructuring example using event.target:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   setUserData((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
 };
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `handleChange`?

Comment: I have. The handleChange is no doing anything: const handleChange = (target) => {};

Comment: That's why your input is not updating.  You have to call an action that updates the value of item.quantity in the redux store during onChange.

Comment: The problem is not that I cannot update redux, I cannot change the input value in the browser. I have disconnected the cart from redux by doing this: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart)) in which case it has nothing to do with redux but the problem persists.

Comment: Yes.  Does this sound like your problem?  You try to type something in the input but nothing appears.  If that's what you're experiencing it's because the value in the redux store never receives the updates from the textbox.  The onChange handler has to send the changes that are typed to redux so that the store value can get updated and thus refreshed on the screen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case. I have created an instance variable.const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(2);, this is not connected to redux. I am now assigning the input to this instance variable but I still cannot edit the input in the browser.

Comment: I can nearly guarantee you it's the problem.  Are you calling `setQuantity` in `handleChange`?  And you have `value={quantity}` for the input now?  `handleQuantity` should have something like `setQuantity(target.value);`

Comment: I have precisely that and the problem still exists. I have added the change to my oriignal question.

Comment: Ah, it's because `cart` isn't getting changed so the rerender is not happening.  Can you add your store reducer and action code?

Comment: Yeah, seeing your action and reducer would help.

Comment: I made a copy of the cart from the reducer so the component has its own copy of the cart. The cart in the reducer and the cart in the component are not the same so the problem I am having could not originate from the cart in the reducer. I have added the code to the original question to demonstrate this.

Comment: I have added the reducer code to the original question but I know if this will be of much help.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised this is not throwing you an error. I was not aware that you could specifiy object properties in a function's parameter's like this: `handleChange = (event.target) =>`. It fails wherever I try it. Are you sure the name and value are being destructured out of it correctly before `setQuantity` is called?

Comment: I have used that quite a bit. I have added another handleChange to the original question showing this. I don't think that's the problem.